# MongoDB error on connection 'MongoServerSelectionError',

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

```
   const uri = 'mongodb+srv:<username>//:<passwod>@chatapp-qrps3.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

   const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

   client.connect(err => {
       console.log(err)
       client.close();
   });
```

> error seems like this
>
> MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection  to
>   40.79.242.22:27017 closed
>       at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/Users/sherin/Desktop/sherinshaju/reactsocket/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:22:11)
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/sherin/Desktop/sherinshaju/reactsocket/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:823:32)
>       at Mongoose.connect (/Users/sherin/Desktop/sherinshaju/reactsocket/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
>       at Object. (/Users/sherin/Desktop/sherinshaju/reactsocket/app.js:28:4)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {   message: 'connection  to 40.79.242.22:27017 closed',   name:
>   'MongooseServerSelectionError',   reason: TopologyDescription {
>       type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
>       setName: null,
>       maxSetVersion: null,
>       maxElectionId: null,
>       servers: Map(3) {
>         'chatapp-shard-00-02-qrps3.azure.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
>         'chatapp-shard-00-00-qrps3.azure.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
>         'chatapp-shard-00-01-qrps3.azure.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
>       },
>       stale: false,
>       compatible: true,
>       compatibilityError: null,
>       logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
>       heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
>       localThresholdMS: 15,
>       commonWireVersion: null   },   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the form of the URI should be in the following manner:

```
const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>.8055@cluster0-mgonm.mongodb.net/test'
```

I think you have missed out the username in your URI.

Comment: its not woking  i just use free mango db server .. but i cant connect to it

Comment: i just forget to add username in that sorry

Comment: please feel free to accept my answer if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: I added the username and password, also tried the pem file to connect but still its not working

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for days to no avail.  Looked at every solution on SO, none of them worked.